# Any suggestion for my music taste considering my Last FM statistics?

Tags: similar-artists, metal

I am an idealist, big metal head fan of Avantasia's band and translator giving Arabic rhetorical translation for several materials and doing song remixing and covering for Japanese, English, French and Arabic songs.

[image]

I hope that you give me some songs, albums and bands suggestions to go further in my philosophical music journey considering my taste.

My Last FM: https://www.last.fm/user/MohamedTBER/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me introduce you to:

### https://www.gnoosic.com/

Basically, you tell it what you like and it suggests artists that other people with similar tastes have liked. It also learns and adapts based on which suggestions you like or don't like. It just gets better as more people use it.

Hope you find a new favourite!

**Note:** I am in no way affiliated with this site, just a music fan who uses it all the time.

Comment: Thanks, dear. you have just given the sustainable development option for my music taste.